# Fundamental solution for a boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find the fundamental solution for the boundary value problems (BVP)
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u+\lambda_i u=0&\text{in }U, &i=1,2.\\
\quad\qquad u=0 &\text{on }\partial U
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda_2<0$ are constants.

I want to find the Green’s functions for the above BVPs taking $U$ to be the unit ball. For that, I would need the fundamental solutions. Could you please give me some hints on how to find the fundamental solutions? Is there some better way to find the Green’s functions for these BVPs?

My comments:

1. If $\lambda <0$, then by the weak maximum principle (Evans, PDE, Chapter 6) we get $u\equiv 0$.
2. Assuming separation of variables $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ we arrive at the ODEs \begin{align}
   X’’-\mu X=0\\
   Y’’+(\lambda+\mu)Y=0
   \end{align}
   where $\mu$ is a constant whose sign would determine the solutions of the above ODEs. If we know the Green’s functions for the above ODEs, can we find the Green’s functions for the first BVPs in terms of these Green’s functions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming $U$ is a ball? Otherwise it is practically impossible to explicitly find the Green's function and certainly you won't be able to achieve using separation of variables.

Comment: Moreover, if $\lambda <0$ then the only solution to $\Delta u + \lambda u=0$ in $U$ and $u=0$ in $\partial U$ is $u=0$ by the maximum principle for elliptic operators (provided $U$ is bounded).

Comment: @JackT I plan to assume U to be a ball when finding the Green’s function. However, I thought we can find the fundamental solutions without this assumption. Nonetheless, I have edited the question to make it more precise. Thanks.

Comment: These are both special cases of the Helmholtz equation, and it's Green's function should be listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)

Comment: @K.defaoite I think the boundary condition assumed in the link you provided is different from the one in my question.